# Logstash grok failing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Am trying to grok a message but its failing with _grokparsefailure in log but doesn't actually say what it's failing on. The  grok query works on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
input {
  file {
  type => "apache-access"
  path => "C:/prdLogs/sent/*"
}
   filter {
   grok {
  match => ['message', '%{IP:clientip} - - \[%{GREEDYDATA:raw_timestamp}   \] "%{WORD:httpmethod} %{NOTSPACE:referrer} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response} "-" "%{NOTSPACE:request}" %{QS:UserAgent} %{WORD:httpmethodO} - - HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion2} "%{WORD:session}:%{WORD:httpmed}" "-" %{NUMBER:duration}' ]
}
   date {
    match => [ "raw_timestamp" , 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z' ]
    target => '@timestamp'
   }
  }

   output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["111.44.44.44:9200"] }
  }
```

The data looks like:

```
199.77.22.22 - - [26/Feb/2017:10:18:45 +0800] "GET /myapp/app/i18n/key/parent.selector.label.select.item/?locale=en_GB&dojo.preventCache=1488075524942 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "https://mywebsite.here.com:31000/myApp/home.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)" GET - - HTTP/1.1 "0000bKOk4n4SSBHuyJJKed085D6:1ap8u8p8j" "-" 3203
199.77.22.22 - - [26/Feb/2017:10:18:45 +0800] "GET /myapp/app/i18n/key/parent.selector.label.no.recently.used/?locale=en_GB&dojo.preventCache=1488075525483 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "https://mywebsite.here.com:31000/myApp/home.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)" GET - - HTTP/1.1 "0000bKOk4n4SSBHuyJJKed085D6:1ap8u8p8j" "-" 3159
199.77.22.22 - - [26/Feb/2017:10:18:46 +0800] "GET /myapp/app/i18n/key/selector.label.selected/?locale=en_GB&dojo.preventCache=1488075525843 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "https://mywebsite.here.com:31000/myApp/home.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)" GET - - HTTP/1.1 "0000bKOk4n4SSBHuyJJKed085D6:1ap8u8p8j" "-" 3600
199.77.22.22 - - [26/Feb/2017:10:18:46 +0800] "GET /myapp/app/i18n/key/actor.selector.label.remove.all/?locale=en_GB&dojo.preventCache=1488075526305 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "https://mywebsite.here.com:31000/myApp/home.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)" GET - - HTTP/1.1 "0000bKOk4n4SSBHuyJJKed085D6:1ap8u8p8j" "-" 3224
199.77.22.22 - - [26/Feb/2017:10:18:46 +0800] "GET /myapp/app/i18n/key/com.label.filter.objects/?locale=en_GB&dojo.preventCache=1488075526711 HTTP/1.1" 200 "-" "https://mywebsite.here.com:31000/myApp/home.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)" GET - - HTTP/1.1 "0000bKOk4n4SSBHuyJJKed085D6:1ap8u8p8j" "-" 3299
```

This is actually an apache access log but I was unable to use COMBINEDAPACHELOG or COMMONAPACHELOG. Same error actually!!

All entries in elasticsearch are tagged as "_grokparsefailure". I ran logstash in debug mode with log.level at debug but am not seeing any errors in the log.

Am using the latest version of logstash.

Please advise.

R2 D2 Thanks, I tried this but no joy :(

I created a patterns file and pasted your pattern. I just changed the payload to just "130.39.22.22 - - [23/Feb/2015:10:18:45 +0800]" and the following was my filter:

```
filter {

grok {
      patterns_dir => ["c:/logstashconfig/patterns"]
      match => ['message', '%{IP:clientip} - - /[%{DATE_CUSTOM:timestamp}/]'] 
    }
date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z' ]
    target => '@timestamp'
  }
}
```

The debug log in logstash:

```
{
      "path" => "C:/prdLogs/sent/test",
"@timestamp" => 2017-03-03T00:06:15.269Z,
      "@version" => "1",
      "host" => "hkw20012125",
   "message" => "130.39.22.22 - -     [23/Feb/2015:10:18:45 +0800]\r",
      "type" => "apache-access",
      "tags" => [
    [0]     "_grokparsefailure"
]   
}
```

Any ideas? Is it the +0800 at the end of the data? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's the +0800, because the pattern was to catch only `26/Feb/2017:10:18:45`. So definitely it'll be throwing a grok parse failure. Remove `+0800` and see

Comment: Thanks! Got it working, I also thought you made a typo with "\[%{DATE_CUSTOM:timestamp}]". I thought it would be \[%{DATE_CUSTOM:timestamp}\]" as I thought since the payload timestamp has bracket, I need to escape both but this wasn't the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think once you have `GREEDYDATA` in your pattern, it means to consider rest of your line from the log:

`GREEDYDATA`'s pattern looks like:

```
GREEDYDATA .* <-- means to capture the entire line
```

And your **grok** match should look something like this if I'm not mistaken:

```
grok {
  match => ['message', '%{IPV4:clientip} - - %{GREEDYDATA:data}']
}
```

unless you need the values to be extracted separately, the above *grok* should do the trick for you. And I think the way you're matching the `timestamp` is wrong. In order to handle your `timestamp` you need to have the below patterns within your **patterns** file:

```
MONTHDAY (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])
MONTH \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b
YEAR (?>\d\d){1,2}
TIME (?!<[0-9])%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}(?::%{SECOND})(?![0-9])
DATE_CUSTOM %{MONTHDAY}[/]%{MONTH }[/]%{YEAR}:%{TIME}
```

And then you could simply use this within your `grok` match:

```
grok {
    match => ['message', '%{IPV4:clientip} - - \[%{DATE_CUSTOM:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:data}']
}
```

Now you'll be able to match the `timestamp` as:

```
date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z' ]
    target => '@timestamp'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I certainly think you are onto something here!! I have tested shortened data/config and it doesn't seem to work post the timestamp. I can't seem to get the time out hence used greedydata. Any ideas on how I can extract [26/Feb/2017:10:18:45 +0800] this? Countless examples on using date but can't see to get something working. I used the example from here goo.gl/oePmZS. I basically want to extract data from message and then add fields such as client_ip, request_url etc etc as well as updating the timestamp

Comment: I've updated the answer, I've tested it and it works for your timestamp! Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: @Kalim Note that, I've only extracted the `26/Feb/2017:10:18:45` part from the log line for the `timestamp`. You could extract it as you wish!

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question as answer too long for these comments!

Answer (score 0):

When you have to build your own patterns, start from the left side, go slowly, and use the [debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com).

If you test this pattern:

```
%{IP:clientip} - - \[
```

it works, but this one:

```
%{IP:clientip} - - \[%{GREEDYDATA:raw_timestamp}   \]
```

doesn't.  Comparing your pattern to the input shows that there aren't spaces between the timestamp and the close bracket.

Changing this part of the pattern to:

```
%{IP:clientip} - - \[%{GREEDYDATA:raw_timestamp}\]
```

works.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my bad, somehow I put spaces in the code editing on the form here but its without spaces within the actual config